# how to choose what type of object to instantiate based on form field?

Tags: java, oop, struts2

i have a struts2 form that takes in a Maintenance object. there are different types of Maintenance - for the sake of brevity let's say there is RemovePart and InstallPart. this form includes fields for both, but the user only sees one - that is based on the user's choice in the first dropdown.

what is the correct (best?) way to determine which Maintenance class to instantiate once my Action receives the data? the best i've come up with so far is below, though i can't help thinking there is a better way to do it.

**EDIT 6/24 14:18 GMT: the RemovedPart and InstalledPart classes have fields that don't correspond to each other.**

```
public class Maintenance {
    private String maintenanceType;

    private String removedSerialNumber;
    private String removedPartName;
    private String removedPartDescription;
    private String removedPartPosition;

    private String installedSerialNumber;
    private String installedPartName;
    private String installedPartSource;

    // getters and setters
}

public class RemovedPart {
    private String serialNumber;
    private String partName;
    private String partDescription;
    private String partPosition;

    public static createRemovedPart(Maintenance maintenance) {
        return new RemovedPart(maintenance.getRemovedSerialNumber(),
            maintenance.getRemovedPartName(), maintenance.getRemovedPartDescription(),
            maintenance.getRemovedPartPosition());
    }

    private RemovedPart() {
      this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
      this.PartName = partName;
      this.partDescription = partDescription;
      this.partPosition = partPosition;
    }

    // getters and setters
}

public class InstalledPart {
    //similar to RemovedPart
}

public class MaintAction extends ActionSupport {
    Maintenance maintenance;

    public String execute() {
        if (maintenance.getMaintenanceType().equals("remove")) {
            RemovedPart removed = RemovedPart.createRemovedPart(maintenance);
        } else {
            // you get the idea
        }
        // more logic
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have errors populating parameters using devMode?

Comment: i have not gotten that far yet -- wanted to hammer out the design of this first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't know how much complex or big is your design, but from what has been shown, **IF** the Maintenance class is declaring duplicate fields (eg. serialnumber for both removed and installed) WITHOUT using both of them at the same time, and hence they're declared only to be filled by the chosen type of maintenance from the page... then you don't need 3 objects, nor duplicate fields:

- declare a single Maintenance class, with single fields
- post it to different actions, one for removal, one for installation.

The type alone will help you to determine which kind of Maintenance you are handling from a method run by both types. However, it would be better to turn it to an Enum:

```
public enum MaintenanceType {
    INSTALLATION(1), REMOVAL(2);

    private int type;

    private MaintenanceType(int t) {
        type = t;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

public class Maintenance {

    private MaintenanceType type;

    private String serialNumber;
    private String partName;

    // getters and setters

    public boolean isInstallation(){
        return type == MaintenanceType.INSTALLATION;
    };
    public boolean isRemoval(){
        return type == MaintenanceType.REMOVAL;
    };
}
```

Comment: oh! so i wouldn't need to bother with creating multiple classes. i could just have one Maintenance object that's used for every instance submitted by the form? and this would be okay even if each maintenance type has a different number of fields (see my above edit)?

Comment: @carrieks It would *work*, but IMO it might not be the *best* solution. You can specify a type based on a hidden field, possibly set dynamically by JavaScript, and/or by checking to see what form parameters are sent. This could be done in an interceptor as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton i do have a field in the form that dictates the type. can you explain more about how you would handle it differently from andrea's suggestion? i am new to struts2, so not aware of all of my options.

Comment: @carrieks The difference is that I might not use a single class to handle both types of requests--but that depends entirely on what kind of, and how much, functionality differs between the two types.

Comment: @DaveNewton totally agree, as stated in my first line up to the bold "if". The answer was written before the edit btw; after the edit, it seems reasonable to use different objects, still depending on the unknown amount of fields that differ.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your Problem correctly you want to have several kinds of Maintenance?

In this case you should think about inheritance

```
public abstract class Maintenance{
//code
}

public class Removal extends Maintenance{
     //has everything Maintenance hase plus extras you can add here
}

public class Installation extends Maintenance{
    //same as Removal
}
```

you could then define a Maintenance like this:

```
Mainenance m = new Removal();
```

you could also use interfaces,

```
public Interface Maintenance{
    private String serialNumber;
    ...
    public String getSerialNumber();
    ...
}
```

your classes could then implement the Interface and you could use them similar to the inherited version.

Comment: thank you, i thought about using an interface or abstract class, but the problem i had with that is that i thought i needed to instantiate the Maintenance object before i could access the maintenanceType field. is this not the case?

Comment: okay I have overseen something, you could also just use the Maintenance class, you have serialNumber and partName in every kind of Maintenance so just change the maintenanceType String and you have no need to name the strings for every different kind of maintenance.
or use enum like Andrea suggested.

Comment: i just realized i left out an important detail. my classes have different fields - i was going for brevity in my example and shot myself in the foot! i will update my question with more details.